# How to split a string in a pandas dataframe with capital letters

Tags: python, pandas

I am playing around with some NFL data and I have a column in a dataframe that looks like:

```
0         Lamar JacksonL. Jackson BAL
1     Patrick Mahomes IIP. Mahomes KC
2         Dak PrescottD. Prescott DAL
3              Josh AllenJ. Allen BUF
4         Russell WilsonR. Wilson SEA
```

There are 3 bits of information in each cell - `FullName`, `ShortName` and `Team` whihc i am hoping to create new columns for.

Expected output:

```
         FullName                ShortName        Team
0         Lamar Jackson           L. Jackson        BAL
1         Patrick Mahomes II      P. Mahomes        KC
2         Dak Prescott            D. Prescott       DAL
3         Josh Allen              J. Allen          BUF
4         Russell Wilson          R. Wilson         SEA
```

Ive managed to get the `Team` but I'm not quite sure how to do all three in the one line.

I was thinking of splitting the string by finding the previous character from the `fullstop` however there are some names that appear such as:

```
Anthony McFarland Jr.A. McFarland PIT
```

which have multiple full stops.

Anyone have an idea of the best way to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Not everybody knows NFL by hearts :-). What's your expected output?

Comment: sorry will edit post!

Comment: @SOK, what site are you pulling the data from? There might be an easier way to get this data without having to manipulate the dataframe (and even return more data)

Comment: hi @chitown88. its from fantasypros site to get some fantasy projections to have a look at

Comment: @SOK, you have a specific url?

Comment: https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/qb.php @chitown88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pandas Series str.extract method is what you're looking for. This regex works for all of the cases you've presented, though there may be some other edge cases.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "bad_col": ["Lamar JacksonL. Jackson BAL", "Patrick Mahomes IIP. Mahomes KC", 
                "Dak PrescottD. Prescott DAL", "Josh AllenJ. Allen BUF", 
                "Josh AllenJ. Allen SEA", "Anthony McFarland Jr.A. McFarland PIT"],
})

print(df)
                                 bad_col
0            Lamar JacksonL. Jackson BAL
1        Patrick Mahomes IIP. Mahomes KC
2            Dak PrescottD. Prescott DAL
3                 Josh AllenJ. Allen BUF
4                 Josh AllenJ. Allen SEA
5  Anthony McFarland Jr.A. McFarland PIT


pattern = r"(?P<full_name>.+)(?=[A-Z]\.)(?P<short_name>[A-Z]\.\s.*)\s(?P<team>[A-Z]+)"
new_df = df["bad_col"].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)
print(new_df)
               full_name    short_name team
0          Lamar Jackson    L. Jackson  BAL
1     Patrick Mahomes II    P. Mahomes   KC
2           Dak Prescott   D. Prescott  DAL
3             Josh Allen      J. Allen  BUF
4             Josh Allen      J. Allen  SEA
5  Anthony McFarland Jr.  A. McFarland  PIT
```

Breaking down that regex:

```
(?P<full_name>.+)(?=[A-Z]\.)(?P<short_name>[A-Z]\.\s.*)\s(?P<team>[A-Z]+)
```

- `(?P<full_name>.+)(?=[A-Z]\.)`
  captures any letter UNTIL we see a capital letter followed by a fullstop/period we use a lookahead (?=...) to not consume the capital letter and fullstop because this part of the string belongs to the short name
- `(?P<short_name>[A-Z]\.\s.*.)\s`
  captures a capital letter (the players first initial), then a fullstop (the period that comes after their first initial), then a space (between first initial and last name), then all characters until we hit a space (the players last name). The space is not included in the capture group.
- `(?P<team>[A-Z]+)`
  capture all of the remaining capital letters in the string (ends up being the players team)

You've probably noticed that I've used named capture groups as denoted by the (?Ppattern) structure. In pandas, the name of the capture group becomes the name of the column and whatever is captured in that group becomes the values in that column.

Now to join the new dataframe back to our original one to come full circle:

```
df = df.join(new_df)
print(df)
                                 bad_col              full_name    short_name  \
0            Lamar JacksonL. Jackson BAL          Lamar Jackson    L. Jackson   
1        Patrick Mahomes IIP. Mahomes KC     Patrick Mahomes II    P. Mahomes   
2            Dak PrescottD. Prescott DAL           Dak Prescott   D. Prescott   
3                 Josh AllenJ. Allen BUF             Josh Allen      J. Allen   
4                 Josh AllenJ. Allen SEA             Josh Allen      J. Allen   
5  Anthony McFarland Jr.A. McFarland PIT  Anthony McFarland Jr.  A. McFarland   

  team  
0  BAL  
1   KC  
2  DAL  
3  BUF  
4  SEA  
5  PIT
```

Comment: this is great - is there anyway to add the column in the existing `df` as opposed to instead of extracting to `new_df`?

Comment: Most certainly, you can just join the result back onto the original dataframe since the indexes already line up:

`df.join(new_df)` should give you the result you're looking for. I'll update my post

Comment: This is great - thanks so much and for the explanation as it helps to understand the regex which can be quite confusing!

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
import re

name = 'Anthony McFarland Jr.A. McFarland PIT'

short_name = re.findall(r'(\w\.\s[\w]+)\s[\w]{3}', name)[0]
full_name = name.replace(short_name, "")[:-4]
team = name[-3:]

print(short_name)
print(full_name)
print(team)
```

Ouput:

```
A. McFarland
Anthony McFarland Jr.
PIT
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that short names would not contain fullstops. So, you can search for the first fullstop from the end of the line. So, from one character before that fullstop until the first space is your short name. Anything coming before one letter before that fullstop is going to be FullName.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'players':['Lamar JacksonL. Jackson BAL', 'Patrick Mahomes IIP. Mahomes KC', 
                         'Anthony McFarland Jr.A. McFarland PIT']})

def splitName(name):
    last_period_pos = np.max(np.where(np.array(list(name)) == '.'))
    full_name = name[:(last_period_pos - 1)]
    short_name_team = name[(last_period_pos - 1):]
    team_pos = np.max(np.where(np.array(list(short_name_team)) == ' '))
    short_name = short_name_team[:team_pos]
    team = short_name_team[(team_pos + 1):]
    return full_name, short_name, team

df['full_name'], df['short_name'], df['team'] = zip(*df.players.apply(splitName))
```